# When does nameof produce a fully qualified name?

Tags: c#, nameof

[Microsoft's docs about the nameof operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof) state that "in the case of a type and a namespace, the produced name is usually not fully qualified".  For example, `nameof(System.Collections.Generic)` yields `"Generic"` and not `"System.Collections.Generic"`.

Note that they say "usually".  So, in which unusual cases is the produced name in fact fully qualified?

Comment: Never, as far as I'm aware - unless the namespace only has one element, e.g. `nameof(System)`. I suspect that "usually" was written by someone who wasn't *absolutely* sure, or wanted to cover the `nameof(System)` case...

Comment: `nameof(System)`.